# SDF file growing forever

Tags: sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I have a code first EF6 model which works well with SqlExpress. When I use SqlCE, I can populate the file ok (380k) but as soon as I try to evaluate a raw sql query, the sdf file starts to grow rapidly and doesn't stop until it hits the default 250MB size limit for SqlCE. Any idea why this file would be growing? I can access the tables ok using a CE browsing tool, it's just when combining with EF that I have the problems.

Comment: Never heard about this before. Which sqlce version? Your connection string?

Comment: ConnectionString: connection = new SqlCeConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0};", Location));  where location is just a path

Comment: Hi Erik. I'm using sql ce 4.0.8854.1 (nuget) with EF 6.1.1 (nuget). I'm doing more experiments and will report back later

Comment: Success! I changed the connection string to include Max Database Size=4091; (which is the biggest size allowed by CE). The raw SQL queries now work, but the sdf file grows and shrinks and grows with each raw sql query. When I populate my sdf file, it's size is 384KB, after I have performed the last raw sql query, it's 290MB !

Comment: Maybe you need indexes?

Comment: Hi Erik, I'm not understanding why I need indexes and why the sdf file is growing with a raw sql query and not with a LINQ query. I looked at the SQL generated by the LINQ and it's very complicated. My hand crafted joins are very simple. What would cause the sdf to grow to such a massive size? In my code first model I have each entity with a primary key (identity type). My object hierarchy is only about 5 deep. It seems that the sdf growing only happens when I add my last entity to the model, before that I can query ok and the sdf does not grow.

Comment: I porobably needs to do sorting or store temporary results, and it needs disk Space in order to do that.

Comment: I figured out the problem - my inner joins were incorrect. There were two issues. I'll describe our hierarchy first: EntityA has many EntityB. EntityB has many EntityC1. EntityB has many EntityC2. EntityB has many EntityC3. There are further children underneath entities C1,C2 & C3. The first issue I had was to use joins in SQL statements when I did not have a WHERE clause (the sql is generated dynamically - it's a querying tool we are building).

Comment: The second, more important issue was that I was joining tables in the lower hierarchy that did not have any relevance on the WHERE clause. For example, SELECT * FROM EntityB [LIST OF INNER JOINS FOR ALL TABLES HERE] WHERE C1.Number=1; In this situation, I should not have any JOINS on C2 or C3. These JOIN mistakes caused SQL Compact Edition to freak out, the file growing wildly. SQL Express was able to function seemingly well despite the SQL errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this myself, in the comments above. In short - too many inner joins, where fewer were required, caused SQL CE to fall over, where SQL Express would tolerate it.